# Can I fetch subtasks of a JIRA issue via XMLRPC (and if so, how to do this)?

Tags: xml-rpc, jira

I have an xmlrpc interface running and am able to fetch issues by ID.
For example, the issue as returned by getIssue('PROJECT-701') contains the fields:

```
affectsVersions .. : [releaseDate,sequence,released,archived,...]
assignee ......... : '...'
components ....... : ...
created .......... : '2011-06-01 16:14:21.217'
customFieldValues  : ...
description ...... : '...'
fixVersions ...... : #()
id ............... : '28602'
key .............. : 'PROJECT-701'
project .......... : 'PROJECT'
reporter ......... : '...'
status ........... : '10032'
summary .......... : '...'
type ............. : '18'
updated .......... : '2011-06-07 12:49:51.363'
votes ............ : '0'
```

now I need to fetch the issue's subtasks. From the html-browser interface, I know that 3 subtasks with IDs 702, 703,...) are present. I am able to fetch the subtasks (as issues) by their issue ID, if those IDs are known (i.e. a getIssue('PROJECT-703') gives the correct return with subtask as issuetype.

**However, how do I get those subtask-ids via xmlrpc from the issue ??**

I find no parent-issue-id in the subtask nor any subtask-ids in the parent.
Is this simply missing from the XMLRPC interface (and I need to use SOAP), or is there a clever trick (text or other special search) to get the info?

If possible, I want to stay with and use XMLRPC instead of SOAP, but a definite confirmation that it is NOT possible in XMLRPC would also be helpful, so I won't waste time trying to get an incomplete xml-rpc interface working...

Additional info:
I am talking to a JIRA 3.13.5 and a getServerInfo request returns:

```
baseUrl .... : ...
buildDate .. : 'Tue Jul 07 00:00:00 CEST 2009'
buildNumber  : '360'
edition .... : 'Enterprise'
serverTime . : '...'
version .... : '3.13.5'
```

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit**: (Sorry misread your question, my answer is for SOAP. With luck the XML-RPC will also have this method).

Unfortunately I'm using version 4.2, so I don't know if this method is available for your version; a quick search of the 3.x documentation suggests it might be.

The only way I've been able to get the substasks for an issue is by using the [getIssuesFromJqlSearch](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getIssuesFromJqlSearch%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

$jira.getIssuesFromJqlSearch($token, 'parent = "PROJECT-703"', 100)

This returns all the subtasks for PROJECT-703

Comment: Seems like my 3.x WSDL does not include the getIssuesFromJqlSearch method, so I have to ask my customer to migrate to 4.x.
It also seems to not be in XML-RPC.